# Is it possible to map Print key in imwheel config file?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

I just managed to configure imwheel to use the Thumb1 and Thumb2 buttons to work as previous/next commands.

`".*"
,Thumb1,Alt_L|Left
,Thumb2,Alt_L|Right`

But now I want to map ALT + Thumb1 to print screen, so I already tried:

1. ALT_L, Thumb1, Print (doesn't work)
2. ALT_L, Thumb1, Control_L|Alt_L|A (key shortcut defined in keyboard settings.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?